# How to customize folding in vim-latex for my sections/commands?

Tags: vim, folding

I've installed the `vim-latex-suite` and I'd like to customize the folding for use with the `labbook` package. The `labbook` package uses `\labday`, `\experiment`, and `\subexperiment` in place of `\chapter`, `\section`, and `\subsection`.

I'd like to customize the folding options with `vim-latex-suite` in Vim so that `\labday`, `\experiment`, and `\subexperiment` are folded like the traditional sectioning commands.

I've tried adding to my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` the following (but it didn't work)

```vim
 " Folding sections
 let g:Tex_FoldedSections = ',labday,experiment,subexperiment'
 " Folding commands
 let g:Tex_FoldedCommands = ',labday,experiment,subexperiment'
```

Can someone show me how to customize the folding for the `labbook` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should put

```
let g:Tex_FoldedSections = 'labday,experiment,subexperiment'`
```

in your `.vimrc` itself. If you take a look at `ftplugin/latex-suite/folding.vim` you'll find:

```vim
if g:Tex_FoldedSections != '' 
    call Tex_FoldSections(g:Tex_FoldedSections,
        \ '^\s*\\frontmatter\|^\s*\\mainmatter\|^\s*\\backmatter\|'
        \. '^\s*\\begin{thebibliography\|>>>\|^\s*\\endinput\|'
        \. '^\s*\\begin{slide\|^\s*\\end{document')
endif
```

Which means that setting `Tex_FoldedSections` after the plugin as already loaded will not work. Also make sure that your sections in your latex file itself are nested correctly.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I need to put the command in `~/.vim/ftplugin` instead of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`. That way it will get loaded first.